# What image to use in .gitlab-ci.yml file for running fastlane in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I want to integrate my fastlane into gitlab-ci and I do not know what image I will use.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately iOS requires the code to be compiled on OSX**

If you have access to a mac you can install a [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html) and [register](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#macos) it to your GitLab repository.

When setting up this runner you should give it a tag name (something like `osx`) and when it comes to selecting the executor, you should choose `shell`(*so the jobs will be run directly on your mac machine*).

After you have a mac runner up and running, you should also make sure you have all the tools that you normally are using like `fastlane`, `xcode` and `Android Studio` setup.

Now in With this setup you don't need to provide any image to your ci job. But rather give it the [tag name](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) you gave your mac runner.